# Quicklist gnome-terminal don't work with byobu profile

Tags: gnome-terminal, quicklists, byobu

Yesterday I tried to create a Desktop quicklist for my gnome-terminal to open byobu with a specific byobu profile.

There's the part of my gnome-terminal.desktop file :

```
[NetBook_Byobu Shortcut Group]
Name=NetBook Byobu
Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=netbook_byobu -x BYOBU_WINDOWS=netbook-session byobu 
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

But nothing appends when I click on the shortcut. So I tried to launch the exec command.

gnome-terminal open with an error :

```
There were an error while the creation of the child process for this terminal

The execution of the Child proccess « BYOBU_WINDOWS=netbook-session » failed (no files or folder of that type)
```

But when I launch byobu with the byobu profile :

```
$ BYOBU_WINDOWS=netbook-session byobu
```

The command works perfectly

I don't understand where the problem is. Maybe someone could help me ?

Best Regard,
Winael

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Custom Byobu
Comment=Custom Byobu Windows
Icon=byobu
Exec=BYOBU_WINDOWS=netbook-session byobu
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=byobu
```

This is based on the default byobu desktop file at     `/usr/share/applications/byobu.desktop`.